# When keyboard opens ListView height changes

Tags: android

I am using a listview to implement a search with array filter. but when my keyboard opens the height of the listview sets to remaining height of the screen and scroll is not working. Once i close the keyboard the height remains same(small) but scroll is working why?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure from the height of `ListView` is `match_parent`:

```
<ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```